# Finding the numbers in the Fibonacci sequence using recursion - how to make it faster?

Tags: java, recursion, fibonacci

My code to Finding the numbers in the Fibonacci sequence is working correct but it is really slooooow. (It is almost impossibleto find number over n=55). Where did I make a mistake?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (; ; ) {
        System.out.println("The value of the fibonacci sequence ");
        Scanner numer = new Scanner(System.in);
        long n = numer.nextLong();
        long result = Fib(n);
        System.out.println(result);

    }
}


private static long Fib(long n) {
    if (n <= 0) { System.out.println("Error"); return 0;}
    else if (n == 1 | n == 2) return 1;
    else return Fib(n-1)+ Fib(n-2) ;

}
```

Comment: See if tail recursion is possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you understand how many times you compute fib(k) for each k? If you want your program to run fast, don't use recursion so blindly, use loop instead:

```java
private static long Fib(long n) {
    long prev = 1;
    long current = 1;
    if (n <= 0) { System.out.println("Error"); return 0;}
    if (n == 1 | n == 2) return 1;
    for (int i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
        long next = prev + current;
        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }
    return current;

}
```

If you want to solve this problem only by recursion, then you need to store already computed results. It can be done either by memoization or by using lazy dynamic programming, and it's way harder than just using loop.

Comment: Fine answer but why consider F0 an error (first fib number F0 = 0).

Answer (score 0):

Even with the proposed improvements by @Jason, this is still an algorithm with **exponential time** complexity of O(2^N).

To reduce the time complexity to O(N), also called **linear time**, I propose the following approach (called "*memoization*", because we save each value we compute and directly return it for O(1) time whenever it is asked, hence the stack frames will be far fewer and will increase at most linearly with the value of "n").

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // receive customer input
    HashMap<Long, Long> map = new HashMap<>();
    long result = Fib(n, map);
}

private long Fib(long n, HashMap<Long, Long> map) {
    if (n <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (map.containsKey(n)) {
        return map.get(n);
    } else {
        map.put(n, Fib(n - 1, map) + Fib(n - 2, map));
        return map.get(n);
    }

}
```

You can compare the two solutions by submitting them in the Fibonacci exercise in [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/fibonacci-number/).

Also, both approaches (yours and a similar memoization approach to mine) are explained under the "Solution" tab in the link above, where you can learn more about the time complexities.

Comment: This is called "memoization", not "memorization".
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization